# Laravel5.8 Pusher Event 500 İnternal Server Error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pusher, laravel-echo, pusher-js

I tring add a chat extension to my web site , watched very much video lesson, Laravel and Pusher using user. Normally website is working

```
broadcasting(new MyEvent('my-event'));
```

but if I add line -before return line- , giving 500 Internal Server Error.
sended message is saving to DB but not return value...
Please help me

My ChatEvent.php

```
use App\Chat;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
....
class ChatEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $chat;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Chat $chat)
    {
        $this->chat = $chat;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PresenceChannel('chat');
    }
}
```

My ChatController.php

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Chat;
use App\Events\ChatEvent;

class ChatController extends Controller
{
public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

public function index(){
    return view('chat.chat');
}

public function fetchAllMessages(){
    return Chat::with('user')->get();
}

public function sendMessage(Request $request){
    $chat = auth()->user()->messages()->create([
        'message' => $request->message
    ]);

    broadcast(new ChatEvent($chat->load('user')))->toOthers();

    return ['status' => 'success'];
}
}
```

VueJs Post And Get codes

```
<script>
    export default {

        methods: {
            fetchMessages(){
                axios.get('messages').then(response =>{
                    this.messages = response.data;
                })
            },

            sendMessage(){
                this.messages.push({
                    user: this.user,
                    message: this.newMessage
                });

                axios.post('messages',{message: this.newMessage});
                this.newMessage='';
            },


        }
    }
</script>
```

Routes and Channels

```
Route::get('/chats','ChatController@index');
Route::get('/messages','ChatController@fetchAllMessages');
Route::post('/messages','ChatController@sendMessage');

Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
  return $user;
});
```

Pusher's AppKey,Secret,ID and Cluster OK,
Broadcaster-Driver: pusher     Everywhere

Comment: You need to check the error log first. Can you share the log in your `storage/logs`?

Comment: looked to console,    writing this--                                    `  "message": "",
    "exception": "Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastException",
    "file": "D:\\LaravelProjeleri\\larachat\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\Broadcasters\\PusherBroadcaster.php",
    "line": 119,   `

Comment: Try checking deeper into the log

Comment: I don't know, how can i ?